# Why does Recyclerview adapter binds all adapter view items on Recyclerview setAdapter and on notifyDatasetchanged?

Tags: adapter, nestedscrollview

Recyclerview inside Nestedscrolview is binding and creating all adapter view items at a time,when I set adapter to recyclerview or notify Recylerview's adapter
how I resolve this issue [I have report this issue in detail at Google code](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=228509)

Comment: Did you find any solution?

Comment: I have not checked this issue since 3 three months ago,you have to  check this issue report in Support Library Version notes  Revision 25.1.0 https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/support-library/revisions.html